# Empty response and errors using CURL with proxy on localhost

Tags: php, apache, curl, web-scraping, proxy

I'm trying to connect to a website using `CURL` with proxy on `localhost` using Xampp.

Here is the `CURL` code:

```
$url= 'https://stubhub.com/';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);

//certificate
$cacert='C:/xampp/cacert.pem';
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );

//SSL
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

//Cookies
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,__DIR__."/cookie.txt");

//User-Agent
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36' );

//Proxy
$proxy = '103.94.120.66:52131';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);


//Errors
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);

$data = curl_exec( $curl );
$info = curl_getinfo( $curl );
$error = curl_error( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );

$allInfo = array("data" => $data, "info" => $info, "error" => $error);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($allInfo);
echo '</pre>';
```

I get 1 of 2 errors each time I run the script:

1-

```
Array
(
    [data] => 
    [info] => Array
        (
            [url] => https://www.stubhub.com/
            [content_type] => 
            [http_code] => 0
            [header_size] => 0
            [request_size] => 225
            [filetime] => -1
            [ssl_verify_result] => 0
            [redirect_count] => 0
            [total_time] => 56.437
            [namelookup_time] => 0
            [connect_time] => 0.296
            [pretransfer_time] => 0
            [size_upload] => 0
            [size_download] => 0
            [speed_download] => 0
            [speed_upload] => 0
            [download_content_length] => -1
            [upload_content_length] => -1
            [starttransfer_time] => 0
            [redirect_time] => 0
            [redirect_url] => 
            [primary_ip] => 103.94.120.66
            [certinfo] => Array
                (
                )

            [primary_port] => 52131
            [local_ip] => 192.168.1.25
            [local_port] => 59947
        )

    [error] => Recv failure: Connection was reset
)
```

2-

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => https://www.stubhub.com/
            [content_type] => 
            [http_code] => 0
            [header_size] => 0
            [request_size] => 0
            [filetime] => -1
            [ssl_verify_result] => 0
            [redirect_count] => 0
            [total_time] => 20.203
            [namelookup_time] => 0
            [connect_time] => 0
            [pretransfer_time] => 0
            [size_upload] => 0
            [size_download] => 0
            [speed_download] => 0
            [speed_upload] => 0
            [download_content_length] => -1
            [upload_content_length] => -1
            [starttransfer_time] => 0
            [redirect_time] => 0
            [redirect_url] => 
            [primary_ip] => 
            [certinfo] => Array
                (
                )

            [primary_port] => 0
            [local_ip] => 
            [local_port] => 0
        )

    [2] => Failed to connect to 103.94.120.66 port 52131: Timed out
)
```

I tried to add this option:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 443);
```

Also tried it with the same port of the proxy:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 52131);
```

But still not working.

I got the proxy from here http://gimmeproxy.com/api/getProxy?supportsHttps=true&maxCheckPeriod=3600&protocol=http

So what to do to make it works?

Is there is a better API/library for proxies or there is something wrong with my code?

Comment: If you have a proxy on localhost, why does your code have `$proxy = '103.94.120.66:52131';`?

Comment: @miken32, What do you mean by "you have a proxy on localhost" ?

Comment: It's requests from localhost to other websites are through my IP, Or the default IP?, I mean it's not changing with each request and that's what I want